# ¿Como comprimir el contenido de un directorio en un zip?

Tags: java, android, zip

**Hola a todos.**

*Yo he formulado esta pregunta con el fin de que me pudieran darme una mano en el obstáculo que se me ha presentado en mi camino.*

### Mi problema

*Mi problema es que quiero poder comprimir los datos o el contenido de una carpeta en un zip, pero mi código actual de compresión, no me ha dado un resultado positivo o el esperado. Por la razón de que no comprime lo deseado*

### Mi código

```
public class Comp {
  public static void zipDir(OutputStream zipFilename, String dir) throws Exception {
        File dirObj = new File(dir);
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(zipFilename);
        System.out.println("Creating : ");
        addDir(dirObj, out);
        out.close();
      }

      static void addDir(File dirObj, ZipOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        File[] files = dirObj.listFiles();
        byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[1024];

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
            addDir(files[i], out);
            continue;
          }
          FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
          System.out.println(" Adding: " + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
          out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
          int len;
          while ((len = in.read(tmpBuf)) > 0) {
            out.write(tmpBuf, 0, len);
          }
          out.closeEntry();
          in.close();
        }
      }

     }
```

***Explicación:*** mi código es muy simple solo paso dos parámetros uno que es el ouputStream donde se podrá escribir y el otro es donde paso la ruta de la carpeta donde copiara el contenido

**Y  llamo estos métodos desde la actividad donde se desencadenara el proceso de compresión de la siguiente manera:**

```
    File file = new File(bb);
    OutputStream os = driveContents1.getOutputStream();
    Comp comp=new Comp();
    try {
        comp.zipDir(os, file.getAbsolutePath());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Se COmprimimio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Si notan donde fallo en mi código o conocen otras formas de poder lograr mi objetivo. Por favor comunicármelo. Gracias.**

Comment: En el resultado es que no imprime. Gracias

Comment: No comprime perdón. Gracias

Comment: Si la ruta existe. Gracias

Comment: "No comprime" significa que el el app escribe el zip exitosamente pero no esta más comprimido que el original? Que tipo de archivos tratas de comprimir?

Comment: Lo que trato de comprimir es una serie de subcarpetas o subdirectorios, donde algunos tendrán archivos dentro. Gracias

Comment: `ZipOutputStream`comprime por defecto. Si te genera el zip con el contrnido esperado y el unico problema es que la taza de compresión no es lo que esperaste, existe la posibilidad que estas comprimiendo archivos que no se pueden comprimir aun más. Eso por ejemplo es posible con imagenes como `.png` o `.jpg` ya con niveles de compresión alta. Textos generalmente tienen mu buenas tazas de compresión. Por eso la pregunta que **tipo** de archivos tratas de comprimir, porque es posible que tu problema no es un problema peros implemente una limitación tecnica de la compresión en general.

Comment: Solo son carpetas y subcarpetas. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu archivo queda vacío porque recursivamente buscas los archivos (que no hay) pero nunca haces entradas para carpetas. Te dejo un ejemplo que funciona (no es código de producción, deberías comprobar integridad del zip producido).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

/**
 * @author snolde
 *
 */
public class Zipper {

    File zip;
    ZipOutputStream output;

    public Zipper(File zip) throws FileNotFoundException{
        this.output = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zip));
    }

    private boolean zipFile(File file){
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            output.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getPath()));
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
              int len;
              while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                output.write(buf, 0, len);
              }
              fis.close();
              output.closeEntry();
              return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean zipDir(File file) {
        try {
            output.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getPath()+File.pathSeparator));
            output.closeEntry();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean add(File... files){
        for (File file : files){
            if (file.isDirectory()){
                zipDir(file);
                add(file.listFiles());
            } else {
                zipFile(file);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void zip(File... files) throws IOException{
        add(files);
        output.finish();
        output.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Zipper z = new Zipper(new File("source.zip"));
            z.zip(new File("src"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```